# Firebird 1.5 / Asp net VS 2010 (legacy database .CDB extension)

Tags: c#, asp.net, firebird

I have an old system which generated me a database in .CDB extension (i run on Firebird-1.5.6.5026-0-Win32) and i can access this database in IBExpert to query and stuff. But i need to write an application in .NET (VS 2010 4.0 framaework) so i can read this database and access some of the data to insert into a table inside SQLServer.

I tried many things, changed the server version and other things but i now all i get is ''Cannot find fbembed.dll'' exception error while trying to open the connection. My FB server doesnt have this file since he uses the 'fbclient.dll' already.

Any thoughts on how to connect my application to this .CDB database?

(this firebird version is the same that the legacy system is running, so i used the 1.7RC firebird .net provider within this server)

The connection string used is:

```
<add name="FirebirdConnectionString" connectionString="User=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey;
   Database=localhost:C:\temp\BD\E‌​CLECTIC.CDB;DataSource=localhost;Port=3051;
   Dialect=3;Charset=NONE;Role=;Connectio‌​n lifetime=15; Pooling=false; 
   MinPoolSize=0; MaxPoolSize=50; Packet Size=8192; ServerType=1;"
   providerName="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient"/>
```

Comment: What connection string are you using? The error message indicates you try to connect with a native, embedded connection instead of the pure .NET driver.

Comment: Also `.CDB` is not a 'normal' Firebird database extension (not even 'legacy`).

Comment: I somehow managed to connect to the database. I can now OPEN the connection. I had an issue with the DLL's, and that is working. But, the problem now is, when i try to retrieve data from the database, the dataRead.Read() statement throws an exception "NullReference" even though i can see that my query count has returned results.

Comment: This is the string im using: <add name="FirebirdConnectionString" connectionString="User=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey;Database=localhost:C:\temp\BD\ECLECTIC.CDB;DataSource=localhost;Port=3051;Dialect=3;Charset=NONE;Role=;Connection lifetime=15;          Pooling=false;           MinPoolSize=0;          MaxPoolSize=50;          Packet Size=8192;          ServerType=1;" providerName="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you really want to use Firebird embedded (which you don't as you also specify `localhost`), you should not specify `ServerType=1`, but either leave it out entirely or set `ServerType=0`.

As to your other problem you mention in the comments, I suggest you check if this solves it and otherwise create a new question with more information.

Comment: For now, i can open the database, now i created a new question regarding the acessing the data. Thank you